# C++: Order of evaluation between cout and a function call

Tags: c++, c++11, cout

I went through few questions about std::cout evaluation order and I understand that there is no sequence point between the args of std::cout, however I am unable to understand how the following code works:

```
saved_fd = dup(STDOUT_FILENO);
std::cout << "Redirecting std out to /dev/null";
redirect_stdout()
<do some stuff>
std::cout << "Restoring std out back to standard output";
restore_stdout();
```

My functions redirect_stdout() and restore_stdout(), using the dup2 calls redirects standard output to /dev/null and restores it back later. I expect the only output to show up on screen is "Redirecting std out to /dev/null". But what I see is "Restoring std out back to standard output".

It appears that redirect_stdout() is getting run before its previous statement.

Just for completeness, here are the definitions of the two methods:

```
void redirect_stdout()
{
  dump_fd = open("/dev/null", O_RDWR, 0777);
  dup2(dump_fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
  cout << endl;
}

void restore_stdout()
{
  dup2(saved_fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
  cout << endl;
}
```

Why don't I see the first cout output?

Comment: My crystal ball says that it's because you don't flush before redirecting. Try `<< std::flush`.

Comment: The standard `iostreams`-based classes use buffering a lot internally. I don’t know if flushing them is enough or if this will always be undefined, but it”s where I’d start.

Answer (score 1):

In both cases, the answer is "buffering".  When you send output to `cout`, it isn't sent to file descriptor 1 until the buffer is full, or until you flush the output.

The fix is to flush the output:

```
saved_fd = dup(STDOUT_FILENO);
std::cout << "Redirecting std out to /dev/null" << std::flush;
redirect_stdout()
<do some stuff>
std::cout << "Restoring std out back to standard output" << std::flush;
restore_stdout();
```

(Instead of `std::flush`, you could also use `std::endl` which outputs a newline and flushes the output.)